# react native, set Android os default lang

Tags: android, mobile, react-native, android-manifest

I am using react-native `v0.36`, and i am building react-native mobile app targeting iOS & Android.

If users have default language of `RTL`, my app looks bad on android. In order for it to look good on Android, i need the app to be open in `en-us` Language only (`LTR` language), no matter what is the Android default language.

Comment: Could you please post a picture, what does it mean, "my app looks bad on android"?

Comment: The App doesn't looks that bad. if i have a _Back button_  on the **left side** and turning left, so an RTL  Android will place the _Back button_ on the **right side**. and stuff like that, it messes the _flex_ positioning.               the RTL os take control on the app style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it!
i needed to force LTR on an RTL OS.
so i used "allowRTL"

in the android/app/src/main/java/com/[app name]/MainApplication.java
i added "onCreate"

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // FORCE LTR
    I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), false);
    ....
}
```

look at:
https://codedump.io/share/UvXEpMY9phKS/1/rtl-is-forced-in-rtl-devices